# ListView.onSaveInstanceState() doesn't work if ListView is not scrolled

Tags: android, android-listview

I recently got a problem in saving the position of the ListView. I'm using `Parcelable state = ListView.onSaveInstanceState()` to store the state of the ListView. and using `fileView.onRestoreInstanceState(state)` to restore the position when needed.

But it stores the value in `state` only if atleast one item is scrolled in the ListView. So if users don't scroll the ListView and `ListView.onSaveInstanceState()` is used, it restores nothing on `fileView.onRestoreInstanceState(state)` and old position remains on the screen.

Is there any particular reason behind it or Am I doing something wrong here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comment from android [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/android/widget/AbsListView.java#AbsListView.onSaveInstanceState%28%29) of `AbsListView.onSaveInstanceState()`:

```
// Remember the position of the first child.
// We only do this if we are not currently at the top of
// the list, for two reasons:
// (1) The list may be in the process of becoming empty, in
// which case mItemCount may not be 0, but if we try to
// ask for any information about position 0 we will crash.
// (2) Being "at the top" seems like a special case, anyway,
// and the user wouldn't expect to end up somewhere else when
// they revisit the list even if its content has changed.
```

Comment: Suppose a user is at the top on the ListView, then ListView contents get changed, user scroll down in the ListView, contents again get replaced by old contents, then the position of the ListView will be scrolled even though it wasn't scrolled by user on old contents of the ListView.